# Unable to recover data from USB stick

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery

My problem is similar to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/701138/unable-to-read-data-from-external-drive) but I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

What I actually did was: I copied some folder (**400 MB**) from my desktop to a USB stick. However, when I ejected the USB stick, it said `Writing data into drive. Please wait.`, but I closed that dialog and removed the stick.

Now, when I remount the USB stick, I just see the folder that I copied *but it's empty.* The size of the USB stick is still showing **400 MB**. Somehow data is allocated but inaccessible.

**My Tries:**

1. When I go to the location of the USB stick (`/media/<username>/sandisk`) and do `ls`, I get `ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error`
2. Also I used **testdisk** as mentioned in [this blog](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/190430-regain-lost-drive-using-test-disk-illustrated-guide.html) but all I see is the empty folder.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: If you pulled it out while it was writing data as you state in your question, the data you put on it is corrupted, and completely useless. Why would you pull it out if it told you to wait?

Comment: I did it in a hurry, and I expected some error when I closed the dialog first. But, it didn't.

Comment: Well, as I've said before, I'm 99% sure your data is corrupted and unusable.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  Favour returned: Question upvoted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is similar to recovering the gasoline you didn't put in the tank of your car because you were in a hurry leaving the gas station.

**It's just not there and *cannot* be recovered.**

### Sorry!